# Is there a way I can retrieve all indicators at once in python talib and btalib?

Tags: python, function, package, ta-lib

There are a lot of indicators you can calculate with the functions built in the talib and btalib libraries. It would be a hassle to gather all information indicator by indicator. Is there a way to do this at once? If so, how should I proceed doing so in python?

http://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/func_groups/pattern_recognition.html

https://btalib.backtrader.com/ta-lib-compat/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine that you want to add all TI at once and save it in a data frame. There is a way to do that as follow:

```
!pip install ta 
from ta import add_all_ta_features
from ta.utils import dropna

# Load datas
df = data.copy() # this is you data and it has to be in the OHLC and volume format 

# Clean NaN values
df = dropna(df)

# Add ta features filling NaN values
df = add_all_ta_features(
    df, open="open", high="high", low="low", close="close", volume="volume", fillna=True)
```

for more details look at the following link:
https://technical-analysis-library-in-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

As for mrjbq7' python wrapper for TA-Lib library - there is such API. The list of available indicator names could be get as demonstrated in [Supported Indicators and Functions](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#supported-indicators-and-functions) section of the documentation and accessing to function by its indicator name is explained in [Abstract API](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#abstract-api) section. Once you get function object you may check out its `info` field for details.